# Root folder is running out of space

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, filesystem, root, memory-usage

I am getting an error: / is running out of space when I work with the creation of docker images.

Then I tried to list the top 10 large files on my computer's filestystem.
It listed out 10 files/folders that are in big size, some of them are cache files.

Now  I'm not sure whether or not i can remove some of the files safely.

Please guide me in this regard. I am aware of the movie files. I want to delete other unnecessary files/directory.

Here is the output of listing command:

```
barry@barry:~$ sudo find / -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort -rh | head -n 10
[sudo] password for barry: 
du: cannot access '/proc/182853/task/182853/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/182853/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied

663M    /home/barry/.cache/tracker/meta.db
595M    /home/barry/.cache/pip/http/0/3/e/f/6/03ef644cae545a4b70d10810314fdbd8a8643d64bc1cf1e94bf575ca
592M    /home/barry/.cache/pipenv/wheels/torch-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
592M    /home/barry/.cache/pipenv/http/0/3/e/f/6/03ef644cae545a4b70d10810314fdbd8a8643d64bc1cf1e94bf575ca
532M    /home/barry/.cache/pipenv/http/9/3/0/5/a/9305a9e52d32a90517dc3735658e0b7b86b46239fd457b2063368d09
497M    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_141.snap
```

Comment: What is the total size of your partition? None of the files is really large by today's standards.
You obviously have some Python virtual environments which hold some data. Whether you could delete them or not is your decision, as you hopefully know whether you still need them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Tracker database](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) takes some space.
Possible action as either to disable Tracker for certain directories or disable the Tracker service at all.

To disable Tracker for a directory, simple put an empty file named **.trackerignore** into each directory to be excluded. However, this will not remove entries or empty the existing database. To do so, run `tracker3 reset --filesystem`.

To disable Tracker completely, run the following commands:

```
systemctl stop --user tracker-extract.service
systemctl stop --user tracker-miner-fs.service
systemctl stop --user tracker-store.service
systemctl stop --user tracker-writeback.service
systemctl mask --user tracker-extract.service
systemctl mask --user tracker-miner-fs.service
systemctl mask --user tracker-store.service
systemctl mask --user tracker-writeback.service
```

To verify that Tracker is really not running anymore, reboot and run `tracker daemon status` to verify.

Disabling Tracker will disable the desktop search of GNOME desktop.

Comment: I am not sure about anything related to tracker. I would look into this topic, Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: The line `/home/barry/.cache/tracker/meta.db` _is_ your Tracker databae.